# @ngtools/webpack TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTsProgram' of undefined

Tags: webpack, angular5

Since I updated to Angular 5 and @ngtools/webpack (from 1.8.0 to 1.9.0) I get a weird error that I can't find out why it is wrong, I just get this error:

```
ERROR in : TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTsProgram' of undefined
  at AngularCompilerPlugin._getTsProgram (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:187:62)
  at getTypeChecker (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:511:43)
  at ast_helpers_1.collectDeepNodes.filter (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/remove_decorators.js:14:60)
  at Array.filter (<anonymous>:null:null)
  at standardTransform (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/remove_decorators.js:14:14)
  at transformer (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/transformers/make_transform.js:14:25)
  at /home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2479:86
  at reduceLeft (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2186:30)
  at /home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2479:42
  at transformRoot (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63992:82)
  at Object.map (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:1693:29)
  at Object.transformNodes (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:63980:30)
  at Object.emitFiles (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:66715:28)
  at emitWorker (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70241:33)
  at /home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70203:66
  at runWithCancellationToken (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70295:24)
  at Object.emit (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:70203:20)
  at defaultEmitCallback (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:33:20)
  at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:241:30)
  at AngularCompilerPlugin._emit (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:741:49)
  at Promise.resolve.then.then.then (/home/patrikx3/Projects/patrikx3/corifeus/corifeus-app-web-pages/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:577:54)
  at <anonymous>:null:null
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Have anyone found this error and why it appears?

Comment: related issue on github: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8525

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have created a hack, that removes the @ngtools/webpack remove decorators for Angular any version (you can upgrade to all packages), it is a gist, the code is here:
https://gist.github.com/p3x-robot/e12ed76acb7033638b4179149546bb73